# How to use sweetalert2 inside modal?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal, sweetalert, sweetalert2

i am using [sweetalert2](http://sweetalert2.github.io), the latest version of sweetalert, how can i call sweetalert inside a model? the alert shows up but it actually blocked by the modal, there is the result i get.[image: result]

it actually blocked by the modal, anything i can do to make it front? thank you!

```
        swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",

        type: "warning",
        confirmButtonText:"Yes",
        confirmButtonColor:"#18a689",
        cancelButtonText:"No",
        showCancelButton: true,
        showLoaderOnConfirm: true
    }).then( function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: [[@{/jobDetails/remove}]],
        type: "POST",
            data:{jobId:id,masterId:masterListId},
        success: function (result) {
            if (result=="success"){
                refreshJobDetails(masterListId)
                reWriteMainTable();
            }
        },
        error: function (thrownError) {

        }
    });
    })
```

Answer (score 18):

I believe your issue is about `z-index` CSS property.

The container of SweetAlert2 has `z-index: 1060` by default. In order to increase it you will need something like this in your CSS styles:

```css
.swal2-container {
  z-index: {X};
}
```

Where `{X}` is a number greater than `z-index` of another modal, e.g. `100000`.

Comment: Is there anyway to make the model itself get grayed out? Even if the `z-index` is more the model itself looks the same. I would like to have the model the base of the sweetalert

Comment: In my case, 
div.swal2-container { z-index: {x}; }
solved the issue.

Comment: Setting `z-index` of `swal2-container` to 1080 did the job as Bootstrap modal's `z-index` is 1072

Answer (score 8):

you just need to increase z-index of `sweet alert` , so you can add `Css` class globally with exactly the same name that `swal` use

i just done with this

```
.swal2-container {
  z-index: 20000 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This helped me:

```css
::ng-deep.swal2-container {
    z-index: 1000000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to bring the sweet alert modal on top using the `z-index`.

```css
.swal-overlay {
    z-index: 100000000000 !important;
}
```

Just check the `z-index` of the modal and put the `.sweet-overlay` `z-index` property more than the modals value.

Answer (score 0):

if anyone still has this issue try using this snippet.
this solved my issue.

```
:host   ::ng-deep .swal2-container {
    z-index: 300000 !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

its working for me in my **ReactJs** project

> public/style.css

```
  .swal2-container.swal2-backdrop-show, .swal2-container.swal2-noanimation {
  
  z-index: 11000;
}
```

> public/index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/style.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is to create another small-size modal for confirmation purposes,
on OK event, process the request else show a cancellation message..

You can shown a modal over another modal by using z-index, but the sweetalert is not recommended with the bootstrap Modal popup

Answer (score 0):

instead of adjusting the `z-index`, you can use the `target` property of sweetalert.

the default target is `body`, you can adjust it to target your modal.

```
Swal.fire({
            target: document.getElementById('form-modal'),
```

ref @mehmetyagci: https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/issues/665#issuecomment-669755719

ref: https://sweetalert2.github.io/#target